# How can i use the data in my dictionary to get the data i want in .txt files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

```
myDictionary = { 
'1-0':[['01', '03', 4889.0, '183', 4851.0, '165'], 
      ['01', '03', 5126.0, '498', 5092.0, '478']],
'2-0': [['02', '03', 3720.0, 1802.3333333333333, 3681.0,1787.3333333333333],
       ['02', '03', 3677.0, 1801.3333333333333, 3645.0,1787.3333333333333]]
}
```

I want to create text files that have the names of the keys in the dictionary. So from the example, after the code is ran it should create `1-0.txt` and `2-0.txt` and each file should contain the values inside the lists except the 2 first elements, so what I will find in `1-0.txt` is :

```
[4889.0, '183', 4851.0, '165']
[5126.0, '498', 5092.0, '478']
```

same sort of operation for `2-0.txt`

Comment: So what have you tried so far?  Do you know about `dict.items()`?

Comment: The values of your dict are not valid Python. Are these nested lists?

Comment: @schwobaseggl My bad i'll adjust the question.

Comment: So, what code have you tried so far? Does it manage to create any files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution

```
import os
def write_from_dict(users_folder):
    for key, value in my_dictionary.items():  # iterate over the dict
        file_path = os.path.join(users_folder, key + '.txt')
        with open(file_path, 'w') as f:       # open the file for writing
            for line in value:                # iterate over the lists
                # write the str representation of the list slice from the 3rd element
                f.write('{}\n'.format(line[2:]))
```

Comment: You should be able to figure out how to edit my code to do that --- however, I'm feeling generous. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @Allen, You should have posted some of your own code where there is a path to a folder involved in it.